# Change height of an animated SVG

Tags: css, svg, background

I'm willing to know how to change the height of a svg I'm using in the body of my file.

I'm willing to change the height of this part of this SVG I found on the internet.

[image]

How can I do it? I'm linking the code of the SVG so you can help me directly from the code. Thank you very much.

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0); display: block; z-index: 1; position: relative; shape-rendering: auto;" width="1980" height="300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 1980 300">
    <g transform=""><linearGradient id="lg-0.8589700868456098" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0" y2="0">
      <stop stop-color="#e3f1ff" offset="0"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#4b00fd" offset="0"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#1b75be" offset="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient><path d="M 0 0 L 0 241.915 Q 165 249.725 330 215.673 T 660 208.18 T 990 199.055 T 1320 208.65 T 1650 230.303 T 1980 211.464 L 1980 0 Z" fill="url(#lg-0.8589700868456098)" opacity="0.4">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="14.285714285714285s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.333;0.667;1" calcmod="spline" keySplines="0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1" begin="0s" values="M0 0L 0 243.84212793573954Q 165 244.198481323735  330 214.97043919697492T 660 203.02580743298734T 990 199.82321083516976T 1320 201.96793159645011T 1650 230.24393184683908T 1980 207.67099842439933L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 235.0618328876254Q 165 269.3721943745703  330 218.17211425063454T 660 226.50305342938853T 990 196.3260923575501T 1320 232.4077939064989T 1650 230.51147502836807T 1980 224.94661631212443L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 205.27226479494266Q 165 240.5155728470433  330 212.79915181526675T 660 213.58512293669696T 990 212.32102514981105T 1320 204.89820182351832T 1650 246.2686309045961T 1980 215.49084241837852L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 243.84212793573954Q 165 244.198481323735  330 214.97043919697492T 660 203.02580743298734T 990 199.82321083516976T 1320 201.96793159645011T 1650 230.24393184683908T 1980 207.67099842439933L 1980 0 Z"></animate>
    </path><path d="M 0 0 L 0 227.032 Q 165 262.125 330 238.153 T 660 207.735 T 990 220.548 T 1320 228.142 T 1650 211.542 T 1980 236.441 L 1980 0 Z" fill="url(#lg-0.8589700868456098)" opacity="0.4">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="14.285714285714285s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.333;0.667;1" calcmod="spline" keySplines="0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1" begin="-2.8571428571428568s" values="M0 0L 0 198.91548309391138Q 165 261.3922476818655  330 234.30112068896972T 660 204.3221098374849T 990 197.40719560146192T 1320 210.24404882431836T 1650 221.90110529290098T 1980 229.98865514501918L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 233.19830897370343Q 165 262.28508633762743  330 238.99758623407547T 660 208.4840242477092T 990 225.62292636527536T 1320 232.06758779859936T 1650 209.26990298551567T 1980 237.85581571111973L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 214.6550175761586Q 165 255.77933395353938  330 205.58046331850787T 660 248.3458831575966T 990 222.1831187074748T 1320 230.19035948492177T 1650 228.0683781289646T 1980 201.17251667905413L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 198.91548309391138Q 165 261.3922476818655  330 234.30112068896972T 660 204.3221098374849T 990 197.40719560146192T 1320 210.24404882431836T 1650 221.90110529290098T 1980 229.98865514501918L 1980 0 Z"></animate>
    </path><path d="M 0 0 L 0 237.421 Q 165 234.24 330 206.641 T 660 208.817 T 990 212.796 T 1320 203.256 T 1650 207.638 T 1980 231.557 L 1980 0 Z" fill="url(#lg-0.8589700868456098)" opacity="0.4">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="14.285714285714285s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.333;0.667;1" calcmod="spline" keySplines="0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1" begin="-5.7142857142857135s" values="M0 0L 0 215.16905431144298Q 165 249.14013005538385  330 208.41012606073144T 660 219.40030814888186T 990 211.27085687418423T 1320 192.61204273811109T 1650 197.1885193400654T 1980 194.1286625359876L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 229.8226321403231Q 165 236.19867929760932  330 203.52409441404166T 660 214.7170706299125T 990 198.3572922664371T 1320 205.71937345561807T 1650 212.78814530052776T 1980 239.82308226121222L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 247.9361109368723Q 165 231.5303336771614  330 210.95445598569952T 660 200.65096582892625T 990 232.7786653161789T 1320 199.8474501390285T 1650 200.50986927760832T 1980 220.1168133404018L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 215.16905431144298Q 165 249.14013005538385  330 208.41012606073144T 660 219.40030814888186T 990 211.27085687418423T 1320 192.61204273811109T 1650 197.1885193400654T 1980 194.1286625359876L 1980 0 Z"></animate>
    </path><path d="M 0 0 L 0 236.55 Q 165 256.696 330 217.771 T 660 229.085 T 990 199.848 T 1320 234.073 T 1650 227.095 T 1980 237.087 L 1980 0 Z" fill="url(#lg-0.8589700868456098)" opacity="0.4">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="14.285714285714285s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.333;0.667;1" calcmod="spline" keySplines="0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1" begin="-8.571428571428571s" values="M0 0L 0 224.7037505439761Q 165 272.6930353316019  330 229.55156582258994T 660 236.61065365348014T 990 219.91504503660167T 1320 230.31466475967437T 1650 220.06173038098666T 1980 207.42481352241373L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 208.16910156011605Q 165 259.1249630688156  330 226.47382965111322T 660 228.26470562084018T 990 214.50370306252307T 1320 233.37870660752753T 1650 248.78240193288315T 1980 229.8215346622372L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 236.77128821460013Q 165 256.3974835288876  330 217.5513635828135T 660 228.94425335689596T 990 199.4737517303316T 1320 234.14322206572314T 1650 227.22631676701283T 1980 237.64106680051827L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 224.7037505439761Q 165 272.6930353316019  330 229.55156582258994T 660 236.61065365348014T 990 219.91504503660167T 1320 230.31466475967437T 1650 220.06173038098666T 1980 207.42481352241373L 1980 0 Z"></animate>
    </path><path d="M 0 0 L 0 208.515 Q 165 252.623 330 209.4 T 660 212.907 T 990 214.014 T 1320 210.712 T 1650 206.499 T 1980 232.652 L 1980 0 Z" fill="url(#lg-0.8589700868456098)" opacity="0.4">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="14.285714285714285s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyTimes="0;0.333;0.667;1" calcmod="spline" keySplines="0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1;0.2 0 0.2 1" begin="-11.428571428571427s" values="M0 0L 0 206.7391959060845Q 165 245.70594371304395  330 203.10592615464478T 660 200.39674383834097T 990 223.5013485428745T 1320 197.11555530025123T 1650 192.20908422829876T 1980 225.460814725169L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 222.47847594882043Q 165 226.43274857890046  330 203.86035526418627T 660 198.8500946506723T 990 246.60167473644773T 1320 194.98517556687025T 1650 247.29227858709245T 1980 200.39555084376045L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 211.39873916492658Q 165 263.85646813786497  330 219.62354308390505T 660 233.22692097790812T 990 198.60435835485188T 1320 232.7961046393257T 1650 229.7087015967473T 1980 244.3330217931673L 1980 0 Z;M0 0L 0 206.7391959060845Q 165 245.70594371304395  330 203.10592615464478T 660 200.39674383834097T 990 223.5013485428745T 1320 197.11555530025123T 1650 192.20908422829876T 1980 225.460814725169L 1980 0 Z"></animate>
    </path></g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e3f1ff, #4b00fd, #1b75be);
   background-size: 100% 100px;
   padding-top: 100px;
}
```

The padding top matches the background block size and is intended to push the svg down the page, the linear gradient is drawing the same as the svg linear gradient hopefully. You may need to pull you top nav up over the padding with a margin: -100px;